# Recursive Collision Detection for Rectangles not quite working

Tags: java, recursion, javafx, collision-detection

I have a bunch of variable sized rectangles, which are laid out randomly in an area.

I am attempting to do (recursive) collision detection that ensures that they do not collide, by shifting their positions.

But, something is still wrong (some of the rectangles still collide), and I can't figure out what.. probably my inability to do recursion right. I would be grateful if someone checked this out.

Here's the code, just copy & paste & run it, and you'll see the result instantly. Requires JavaFx:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.*;

public class Example extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Pane root = new Pane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        stage.setTitle("Collision Problem");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> System.exit(0));
        stage.show();

        run();
    }

    private static class Node2D {

        private double x, y, w, h;

        public Node2D() {
            w = randInt(40, 80);
            h = randInt(20, 40);
        }

        public void setPosition(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public double getWidth() {
            return w;
        }

        public double getHeight() {
            return h;
        }
    }

    private static class LayoutEntity {

        private Node2D obj = new Node2D();

        private double x, y;

        public void setLocationInLayout(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public double getXInLayout() {
            return x;
        }

        public double getYInLayout() {
            return y;
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        LayoutEntity[] entitiesToLayout = new LayoutEntity[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < entitiesToLayout.length; i++)
            entitiesToLayout[i] = new LayoutEntity();

        randomizePositions(entitiesToLayout);

        collisionDetection(entitiesToLayout);

        for (LayoutEntity entity : entitiesToLayout) {
            Node2D node = entity.obj;
            node.setPosition(entity.getXInLayout(), entity.getYInLayout());
        }

        // Print possible collisions
        displayNodes(entitiesToLayout);
    }

    private void displayNodes(LayoutEntity[] all) {
        for (LayoutEntity entity : all) {
            Node2D node = entity.obj;

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(node.x, node.y, node.w, node.h);
            rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            rect.setFill(null);

            root.getChildren().add(rect);
        }
    }

    private void randomizePositions(LayoutEntity[] entities) {
        for (LayoutEntity entity : entities) {
            entity.setLocationInLayout(randInt(0, 512), randInt(0, 512));
        }
    }

    private void collisionDetection(LayoutEntity[] entities) {
        collisionDetection(Arrays.asList(entities));
    }

    private void collisionDetection(Collection<LayoutEntity> c) {

        List<LayoutEntity> collisions = new ArrayList<>();

        for (LayoutEntity e1 : c) {
            for (LayoutEntity e2 : c) {
                if (e1 == e2)
                    continue;
                boolean collides = checkAndResolveCollision(e1, e2);
                if (collides)
                    collisions.add(e1);
            }
        }

        checkRecursively(collisions, c);
    }

    private void checkRecursively(List<LayoutEntity> collisions,
            Collection<LayoutEntity> all) {

        if (collisions.isEmpty())
            return;

        for (LayoutEntity e1 : all) {

            for (int i = 0; i < collisions.size(); i++) {

                LayoutEntity e2 = collisions.get(i);

                if (e2 == e1)
                    continue;

                boolean collides = checkAndResolveCollision(e1, e2);
                if (collides) {

                    if (collisions.contains(e1))
                        continue;

                    collisions.add(e1);

                    checkRecursively(collisions, all);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkAndResolveCollision(LayoutEntity e1, LayoutEntity e2) {

        Node2D n1 = e1.obj;

        // Ideally, I also want to add a gap around the boxes
        double extraSpace = 0;

        double w1 = n1.getWidth() + extraSpace * 2;
        double h1 = n1.getHeight() + extraSpace * 2;

        Rectangle2D b1 = new Rectangle2D(e1.getXInLayout() - extraSpace,
                e1.getYInLayout() - extraSpace, w1, h1);

        Node2D n2 = e2.obj;

        double w2 = n2.getWidth() + extraSpace * 2;
        double h2 = n2.getHeight() + extraSpace * 2;

        Rectangle2D b2 = new Rectangle2D(e2.getXInLayout() - extraSpace,
                e2.getYInLayout() - extraSpace, w2, h2);

        if (b1.intersects(b2)) {

            Point2D trans = getMinimumTranslation(b1, b2);

            double x = e1.getXInLayout() + trans.getX();
            double y = e1.getYInLayout() + trans.getY();

            e1.setLocationInLayout(x, y);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Point2D getMinimumTranslation(Rectangle2D source, Rectangle2D target) {

        double mtdx, mtdy;

        Point2D amin = new Point2D(source.getMinX(), source.getMinY());
        Point2D amax = new Point2D(source.getMaxX(), source.getMaxY());
        Point2D bmin = new Point2D(target.getMinX(), target.getMinY());
        Point2D bmax = new Point2D(target.getMaxX(), target.getMaxY());

        double left = (bmin.getX() - amax.getX());
        double right = (bmax.getX() - amin.getX());
        double top = (bmin.getY() - amax.getY());
        double bottom = (bmax.getY() - amin.getY());

        if (left > 0 || right < 0)
            return Point2D.ZERO;

        if (top > 0 || bottom < 0)
            return Point2D.ZERO;

        if (Math.abs(left) < right)
            mtdx = left;
        else
            mtdx = right;

        if (Math.abs(top) < bottom)
            mtdy = top;
        else
            mtdy = bottom;

        // zero the axis with the largest mtd value.
        if (Math.abs(mtdx) < Math.abs(mtdy))
            mtdy = 0;
        else
            mtdx = 0;

        return new Point2D(mtdx, mtdy);
    }

    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you honestly believe that someone will dive into your code? Isolate fragment into test and post it.

Comment: If you want your whole code to be reviewed, better post it at [stack exchange code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's funny, it's usually when people DON'T post an MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) people will complain.. I've never encountered it this way around... Most of the code is simple "boilerplate" and simply necessary to display the example in its full glory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading your code, what I can predict is, the problem is in the logic. Inside `checkAndResolveCollision()`, when you assigning a new co-ordinate to the `Node` using

```
e1.setLocationInLayout(x, y);
```

you miss to check whether the new co-ordinate that you have assigned to this node, overlaps any of the other node's which we have already checked against this one.

You will have to generate the logic, as to whenever you are changing the co-ordinate of a Node, it must again be checked against every other Node

*Hope it helps*

Comment: Nicely spotted, detective! That indeed was the problem! I fixed it with another recursive check inside the checkRecursively()-method.